# Problem with Doctrine generate model from YAML (symfony)

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, yaml

I have written my schema.yml but I have two problems when I try to generate model :

1. I have disabled table class generate with `generateTableClasses: false` but the classTable.class.php are generated.
2. I have specified packages to generate classes in subfolders, and I want to know how don't generate `/model/doctrine/packages/PluginMyClass.class.php` ? I have tried options :

   `packagesPath: /`

   `packagesFolderName: /`

But my package is generated in `/model/doctrine/MyPackage/MyClass.class.php`

**AND** in `/model/doctrine/packages/PluginClass.class.php`

I give you a part of my schema.yml :

```
generateTableClasses: false
packagesPath: /
packagesFolderName: /

Personnage:
  tableName: personnage
  package: Personnage
  columns:
    # Here my columns

Guerrier:
  package: Personnage
  inheritance:
    extends: Personnage
    type: simple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have disabled table class generate
>   with generateTableClasses: false but
>   the classTable.class.php are
>   generated.

That shouldn't be in schema. Patch your `ProjectConfiguration.class.php` like so:

```
>?php
public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager)
{
  $options = array('generateTableClasses' => false);
  sfConfig::set('doctrine_model_builder_options', $options);
}
```

> and I want to know how don't generate
>   /model/doctrine/packages/PluginMyClass.class.php
>   ?

Try a solution described here - http://melikedev.com/2009/10/26/symfony-w-doctrine-package-over-ride-in-schema-yml/

Hope that helps.